# Visual Studio 2017 - Unable to start program http://localhost

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a problem with my IDE. Simply in asp.net web application project when I try to start debugging with **Chrome**, the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prHhc.png) shows up.

The problem doesn't occur selecting Edge browser for debugging by the way.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/prHhc.png

Also I have no problem when I unclick "Enable javascript debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)".

Comment: whether this project was created by the VS2017 or old VS version? If you create a new ASP.NET app, and then debug it using the Chrome, how about the result? Please also make sure that you use the latest VS2017 version. I debug the web app normally using the Chrome in my side even if I enable the Javascript debugging option. I think we have to make sure that whether it is related to the VS IDE or the project itself. In addition, not debug your app, just run it using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", how about the result?

Comment: I tried with different project the problem is occurs again. Im using latest version of vs2017. Also if I try to "start without debugging", situation is same. Actually this problem began after I uptade my vs to new version of 2017.

Comment: how did you update your VS? Do you install the update package from the extensions and updates windows in VS2017? As you said that it still has this issue if you run your app with "start without debugging", at least, we could know that it is not the VS debugging issue. Could you repair your VS?

Comment: I've updated Visual Studio 2017 to the latest Version and rebooted the computer. The problem disappeared.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Workaround is below. Clearly a bug, please fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For me, the solution (workaround) is to turn off JavaScript debugging on Chrome, which I believe is a new feature introduced in `VS 2017`.

Go to: Tools **>** Options **>** Debugging **>** General and turn off the setting for:

<kbd>Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)</kbd>

Comment: Pretty annoying that we have to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Funny how these things just popup randomly at various points. It's not like we all got it back in March or so.  It happened to me because I was also using Google Tag Manager's debug window and it caused similar activity as the Inspect window.

Comment: @muhammadAfsal what if I want to be able to continue debugging Javascript?

Answer (score 8):

The problem solved by following setting
VS-2017 -> Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General: Uncheck/Disable the "Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE)" option

I tried the other options provided above such as Restart VS-2017, closing browser opened earlier but that didn't solved this problem. I have installed VS-2017 Community Edition one week back only.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**
Make sure any previous opened Chrome debugging windows are closed before you start a new debugging session

**Explanation**
When I started debugging from VS2017 a new Chrome window opened and when I stopped debugging the Chrome debugging window were shut down and then I could start debugging again.

If the Chrome debugging window wasn't shut down upon debugging stop for whatever reason, and I started a new debugging from VS then it opened a new tab in the previously opened Chrome debugging window, and I had the error and couldn't start debugging.

So I closed the debugging window manually before I started debugging and it worked again.

Comment: Yes should close the  previous opened Chrome debugging windows

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, solved it by restarting Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Not enough reputation for a comment, but yea ,you are right, it should be a comment.Gonna leave as it is because it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I want share my my solution. ***Just restart your Application and App Poll in IIS***. Hope it helps you.